# How to implement Webpack Encore in Twig 2.x WITHOUT Symfony4

Tags: twig, webpack-encore, twig-extension

I think the question is self-explanatory, Twig documentation is not enough.

I tried to install using this:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html

But got error using **encore_entry_link_tags** / **encore_entry_script_tags**

I found that those functions are in **\Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\Twig\EntryFilesTwigExtension** and tried to "simply add the extension" using this doc:

- https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#using-extensions

But I got errors because it needs a **ContainerInterface**, after understanding what is it, it seems to be a dependency injection from Symfony, so at the end, I need Symfony to make this work.

There is any tutorial or documentation that let me do these two components to work?